# How do I split an xml variable using xquery?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xquery

I have a scalar xml variable:

```
DECLARED @XML xml =
'<rows>
    <row>
        <column1 attrib="" />
        <column2 attrib="" />
    </row>
    <!-- ... -->
</rows>';
```

I would like to split the data so that each row's xml is assigned to a new record in a table:

```
Id | ... | XML
1  |     | '<row><column1 attrib="" /><column2 attrib="" /></row>'
2  |     | etc.
3  |     | etc.
```

I haven't quite grasped xquery so I'm having trouble writing an insert statement that does what I want.

```
INSERT into MyTable( [XML])
SELECT @XML.query('row')
```

Now I know **something** is happening but it appears rather than doing what I intended and inserting multiple new records it is inserting a single record with an empty string into the `[XML]` column.

What am I not getting?

### Clarification

I am not trying to get the inner text, subelements or attributes from each row using `value(...)`. I am trying to capture the entire `<row>` element and save it to a column of type `xml`

I've experimented with `nodes(...)` and come up with:

```
INSERT into MyTable([XML])
SELECT C.query('*')
FROM @XML.nodes('rows/row') T(C)
```

Which is closer to what I want but the results don't include the outer `<row>` tag, just the `<column*>` elements it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T-SQL Script:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;

DECLARE @x XML =
'<rows>
    <row Atr1="11" />
    <row Atr1="22" Atr2="B" />
    <row Atr1="33" Atr2="C" />
</rows>';

DECLARE @Table TABLE(Id INT NOT NULL, [XMLColumn] XML NOT NULL);

INSERT  @Table (Id, XMLColumn)
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) AS Id,
        a.b.query('.') AS [XML]
FROM    @x.nodes('//rows/row') AS a(b);

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table t;
```

Results:

```
Id XMLColumn
-- --------------------------
1  <row Atr1="11" />
2  <row Atr1="22" Atr2="B" />
3  <row Atr1="33" Atr2="C" />
```

Comment: Aah, it was the `'.'` not `'*'`. That's what I was missing. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.nodes(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to project each `<row .../>` as a row and the extract the attributes of interest using [`.value(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx). Something like:

```
insert into MyTable(XML)
select x.value('text()', 'nvarchar(max)') as XML
from @XML.nodes(N'/rows/row') t(x);
```

`text()` will select the inner text of each `<row .../>`. You should use the appropriate expression (eg. `node()` or `@attribute` etc, see [XPath examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx)), depending on what you want from the row (your example does not make it clear at all, with all those empty elements...).